# Detect Element Load via Controller in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, c3

i have a angularjs project and i am using angular-ui (bootstrap) Tabs.
my problem is that i am using charting tool with it.

is there any way to detect that the tab has been completely loaded.

```
<tabset justified="false">
    <tab heading="Yesterday"  ng-controller="yesterdayCtrl" ng-cloak >
        <div ng-include="'templates/tabViews/yesterday.html'" scope="" onload="" ></div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Weekly" ng-controller="weeklyCtrl" >
        <div ng-include="'templates/tabViews/weekly.html'" scope="" onload="" ></div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Monthly"></tab>
    <tab heading="Yearly"></tab>
</tabset>
```

each ng-include contains details tabs with lots of charting inside it. the issue is that the charts are not getting displayed when ta is clicked and view. i have to re call all the function to redraw. 
i see thisis beacause the charts get drawn in the background.

i am using c3.js with d3.js

```
DrawService.drawSpline =  function(ele,data) {
    c3.generate({
        bindto: '#'+ele,
        data: data
    });
}
```

Comment: You can use the onload attribute to call a function on load from the available scope

Comment: onload is not best suited with angular. angular.bootstrap(document,["myApp]); is same as onload with some difference. the problem here is not page load but detecting element lload and render.

Comment: <div ng-include="'templates/tabViews/yesterday.html'" scope="" onload="onLoadOfTemplate()" ></div> this will call the function when the teplate is loaded .. where as this angular.bootstrap(document,["myApp]); is called when your main module of angular is loaded

Comment: thanks kushal i have tried this. but the problem is i need to render once

Comment: Is it that when the tabs are switched the templates are again loaded and rendered?

Answer (score 0):

temporary fix

```
<tabset justified="false">
<tab heading="Yesterday"  ng-controller="yesterdayCtrl" ng-click="loadYes()">
<div ng-include="'templates/tabViews/yesterday.html'" scope="" onload="loadYes()" ng-cloak ></div>
</tab>
<tab heading="Weekly" ng-controller="weeklyCtrl" ng-click="loadWeek()">
<div ng-include="'templates/tabViews/weekly.html'" scope=""  ng-cloak></div>
</tab>
<tab heading="Monthly" ng-controller="monthlyCtrl" ng-click="loadMonth()">
<div ng-include="'templates/tabViews/monthly.html'" scope="" n ng-cloak></div>

</tab>
<tab heading="Yearly" ng-controller="yearlyCtrl" ng-click="loadYear()">
    <div ng-include="'templates/tabViews/yearly.html'" scope=""  ng-cloak></div>


</tab>

</tabset>
```